# Missing object or bucket in path when running on Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When trying to run a pipeline on the Dataflow service, I specify the staging and temp buckets (in GCS) on the command line. When the program executes, I get a RuntimeException before my pipeline runs, where the root cause is that I'm missing something in the path.

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing object or bucket in path: 'gs://df-staging-bucket-57763/', did you mean: 'gs://some-bucket/df-staging-bucket-57763'?`

`gs://df-staging-bucket-57763/` already exists in my project, and I have access to it. What do I need to add to make this work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The DataflowRunner requires that the staging location and temp locations be a location *within* a bucket rather than the top-level of a bucket. Adding a directory (such as `--stagingLocation=gs://df-staging-bucket-57763/staging` or `--tempLocation=gs://df-staging-bucket-57763/temp`) to your arguments (for each of the `stagingLocation` and `gcpTempLocation` arguments) will be sufficient to run the pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

Update run configuration as below:

1. uncheck flag "Use Default Dataflow options" under the Pipeline Arguments tab. Select pipeline arguments manually.
2. Keep blank value for "Cloud Storage staging location".